# Is it natural sounding to use "passing through filters" figuratively? And if not, would you please suggest something that has the same meaning?

Tags: grammar, expressions, idioms, syntactic-analysis

If we want to say a particular company is very selective about the employees they choose, can we use the following sentence: "Employees must pass (OR be passed!?) through a lot of filters to be selected for the job."? Would it sound natural to use "passing through filters" figuratively?

Comment: It is not an obviously bad metaphor, but whether it is a good one is a matter of opinion, and may partially depend on the context. It is thus unlikely that anybody will be able to offer a definitive answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot @jsw29. What if you were writing a formal essay? What would you write to convey the intended point in a way that would be both natural and professional?

Comment: And how can we tag someone here? :/

Answer (score 1):

Candidates must undergo **a screening process**

> - [screening](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/screening) the activity of a person who screens, as in ascertaining the qualifications of applicants.
> - [Screening](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E39904_01/hcm92pbr0/eng/hcm/herm/concept_UnderstandingtheScreeningProcess-947bff.html) is the process used by recruiters to evaluate a list of potential candidates and narrow the list to the most qualified applicants. ...

All candidates must undergo a thorough screening process so we can hire the right person for the job.

Comment: that sounds perfect thanks a lot